# ASP.NET Web Service call with Client Credentials

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-client

I am facing a situation with a 3rd party web service that I need to call. When I make a reference to the web service, I get the following configuration in my app.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="GetCompanyInfoSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="">
                        <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                    </transport>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="GetCompanyInfoSoap1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="">
                        <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                    </transport>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="GetCompanyInfoSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false">
                    <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                </httpsTransport>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://api.capitaliq.com/ciqdotnet/api/2.0/GetCompanyInfo.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GetCompanyInfoSoap"
            contract="GetCompanyInfoSvc.GetCompanyInfoSoap" name="GetCompanyInfoSoap" />
        <endpoint address="https://api.capitaliq.com/ciqdotnet/api/2.0/GetCompanyInfo.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="GetCompanyInfoSoap12"
            contract="GetCompanyInfoSvc.GetCompanyInfoSoap" name="GetCompanyInfoSoap12" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then I call the service using my std. approach as shown:

```
GetCompanyInfoSvc.GetCompanyInfoSoapClient p = new WindowsFormsApplication1.GetCompanyInfoSvc.GetCompanyInfoSoapClient("GetCompanyInfoSoap");
p.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "cccccc";
p.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "ccccg";
GetCompanyInfoSvc.CompanySummary[] summ = p.GetCompanyInfo(new int[] { 18511 });
```

However, the call always fails with 'Authentication Required' which seems like the username/pw are not getting through. I have tried the std. approach of adding it as an ASMX web reference and used the call:

```
GetCompanyInfo c = new GetCompanyInfo();
c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ccccc", "cccg");
CompanyDetail[] details = c.GetCompanyDetail(new int[] { 18511 });
```

This doesn't work either. Gives me the same 'Authentication required' error.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Just an update, I did change the transport clientCredentialType to 'Basic' instead of 'None' but it still didn't work. I do know that WCF does that for ASMX services and doesn't add the 'Basic' authentication for transport.

Comment: GetCompanyInfoSoap1 certainly won't work because you've set the Transport="None" and the client endpoints are both HTTPS. You just need to determine if the third-party service requires user/password for the transport or the message itself. I think for enforcing message security you'll need a shared certificate in addition to a valid user name & password.